# UWP/WinUI: Override TextBox.HeaderTemplate so that it can display complex content

Tags: uwp, styles, datatemplate, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Is it possible to override `TextBox.HeaderTemplate` so that it can display complex content - like a `StackPanel` with multiple items?

```xml
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I'm trying to do this for testing and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
```

Comment: Sure. The rule here is that I cannot accept my answer until 24 hours or more has passed.